Properly type a function which returns a value when an optional parameter is set
(This feels like something that could be expressed in and solved by monad world if I had the right vocabulary?)
Consider a function that takes an optional/nullable parameter, and returns a value iff the parameter was non-null:
function addOne(num: number | null | undefined = null): number | null | undefined {
  if (num === null || typeof num === "undefined") return num;
  return num + 1;
}

The problem with the above typing is that it doesn't correlate the optionality of the input with the optionality of the output - so:
if (num !== null && typeof num !== "undefined") {
  // Static type checker can verify here that num is set
  num = addOne(num);
  // ...but not here, because addOne's signature doesn't guarantee it
}

I considered overloading the method signature (as suggested here) with e.g.
function addOne(num: number): number;
function addOne(num: null): null;
function addOne(num: undefined): void;
function addOne(num: number | null | undefined = null): number | null | undefined {
  ...
}

...but as I saw in my own attempts and noted on the above-linked TypeScript doc page:

we can’t invoke it with a value that might be a [number or null/undefined], because TypeScript can only resolve a function call to a single overload
...Always prefer parameters with union types instead of overloads when possible

So what's the consistent way to type a function like this, so that it can be called with union-typed parameters but will preserve the correlation in cases where more constraints are known?

You could use a generic conditional type as shown here. Note that this doesn't really validate that the implementation adheres to that... but neither does your version above so I assume that's out of scope. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

As far as I can tell, yes that seems to work! In my actual use-case number is replaced with a generic type & still trying to wrap my head around how to make that work... But that's on me I guess and the SO question is the SO question :D

You could add a specific overload for each relevant subtype of the union number | null | undefined, but that quickly gets out of hand:
// call signatures
function addOne(num: number): number;
function addOne(num: null): null;
function addOne(num: undefined): undefined;
function addOne(num: number | null): number | null;
function addOne(num: number | undefined): number | undefined;
function addOne(num: null | undefined): null | undefined;
function addOne(num: number | null | undefined): number | null | undefined;

// implementation
function addOne(num: number | null | undefined = null): number | null | undefined {
  if (num === null || typeof num === "undefined") return num;
  return num + 1;
}

addOne(1); // number
addOne(null); // null
addOne(undefined); // undefined
addOne(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 2 : null); // number | null

Yuck. Or, you could add just a single generic call signature that returns a distributive conditional type which naturally acts that way:
// call signature
function addOne<T extends number | null | undefined>(
  num: T
): T extends number ? number : T;

// implementation
function addOne(num: number | null | undefined = null): number | null | undefined {
  if (num === null || typeof num === "undefined") return num;
  return num + 1;
}

addOne(1); // number
addOne(null); // null
addOne(undefined); // undefined
addOne(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 2 : null); // number | null

Note that this is still an overload (there's a call signature separate from the implementation), and as such, the implementation isn't fully checked; see microsoft/TypeScript#22609.  You could change the body of the function to be just return 3 and TypeScript would be happy. So whenever you use overloads, you need to take care that the implementation satisfies the call signature yourself.
Playground link to code
